# How do I close find-and-replace pane in Atom Editor?

Tags: atom-editor

How do I close find-and-replace pane?
The pane does not close despite pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

I using macOS 10.12.4 and Atom 1.16.0.

Answer (score 0):

### First focus the panel

It won't close on <kbd>Esc</kbd> everywhere in the UI, but it will do so when the find panel is already focused. So do either of the following to focus the panel:

1. Press the key combo for the find panel

   - <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> on Mac
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> on Windows/Linux
2. Or click into the panel

And then press 
<kbd>Esc</kbd> to dismiss.

Same thing for the project find panel, except you use a different keystroke (e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> for Mac).

### Rebinding the "find" keystroke

If you prefer you can also override the find keystroke. By default, this keystroke will open the find panel, but if you press it again, it will not close it. But you can re-bind it to instead toggle the panel on/off, if you prefer that.

To open your keybindings, you can use the Command Palette to run the "Application: Open Your Keymap" command, or use the "Keymap" menu item in the application menu. It will open the `keymap.cson` file in your Atom config directory. Add the appropriate entry below, save the file, and it should be active immediately. Simply comment it out or remove it to disable the keymap.

I'll show for both regular find panel and project-level find below. You can use either or both, just omit one of the lines if you don't want both of them.

#### Mac

```coffee
'atom-text-editor':
    'cmd-f': 'find-and-replace:toggle'
    'shift-cmd-f': 'project-find:toggle'
```

#### Windows / Linux

```coffee
'atom-text-editor':
    'ctrl-f': 'find-and-replace:toggle'
    'shift-ctrl-f': 'project-find:toggle'
```